# Grid.Children.Add nothing showing

Tags: vb.net, silverlight-5.0

I'm trying to add the words ONE, TWO, THREE to my 3 by 3 LayoutRoot Grid diagonally top left to bottom right.

But I'm not getting anything on screen. I have Gridlines turned on in the XAML, so I can see 3 x 3 Grid, but not the words ONE, TWO, THREE.

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
Partial Public Class MainPage
Inherits UserControl

Dim textblock1 As TextBlock
Dim textblock2 As TextBlock
Dim textblock3 As TextBlock

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub

Public Sub Test()


    textblock1.Text = "One"
    textblock2.Text = "Two"
    textblock3.Text = "Three"

    Grid.SetRow(textblock1, 0)
    Grid.SetColumn(textblock1, 0)
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(textblock1)

    Grid.SetRow(textblock2, 1)
    Grid.SetColumn(textblock2, 1)
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(textblock2)

    Grid.SetRow(textblock3, 2)
    Grid.SetColumn(textblock3, 2)
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(textblock3)
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the text blocks, preferably in your `Test()` method, **and** you need to *call* `Test()`, for example from `New()`:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Test()
End Sub

Public Sub Test()

    textblock1 = New TextBlock
    textblock2 = New TextBlock
    textblock3 = New TextBlock
    ...
```